# Maps API doesn't show the map

Tags: javascript, json, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm using the follow code to show a map with various points for a `json` archive in a folder inside the wamp www folder. But, the result is a blank page.

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Marker Labels</title>
    <style>
      html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
      #map {
        height: 100%;
      }
    </style>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=NUMBER OFMYKEY&signed_in=true"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js">
    <script>
      google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

dados.json

```
{
        "universities": [
            {
                "title": "Aberystwyth University",
                "website": "www.aber.ac.uk",
                "phone": "+44 (0)1970 623 111",
                "lat": 52.415524,
                "lng": -4.063066},
            {
                "title": "Bangor University",
                "website": "www.bangor.ac.uk",
                "phone": "+44 (0)1248 351 151",
                "lat": 53.229520,
                "lng": -4.129987},
            {
                "title": "Cardiff Metropolitan University",
                "website": "www.cardiffmet.ac.uk",
                "phone": "+44 (0)2920 416 138",
                "lat": 51.482708,
                "lng": -3.165881}
        ]
    }
```

app.js

```
function getLocal(callback){
  $.getJSON("localhost/dados/dados.json", callback);
};

  function initialize() {
    var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(52.415524, 4.063066);
    var mapOptions = {
      zoom: 10,
      center: myLatLng,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP

    }
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'),mapOptions);

  getLocal(function(data){
    var locals = data.universities;
    var local, latLng;

    for(i in universities){
      local= universities[i];
      latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(local.lat, local.lng);

      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: latLng,
        label: "D",
        map: map,
        title: local.title
      });
    }
  });
}
```

UPDATE:

The follow error in console:

```
jquery.min.js:4 XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///C:/Users/noot01/Dropbox/Lucas%20Torres/Projetos/_teste/dengue/denge_teste2/localhost/dados/dados.json. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.
```

Comment: Are you really going to load the JSON using the file:// protocol in production? That is what isn:t working per the error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing the closing  `</script>` for `<script src="app.js">`

Additionally:
2 errors in this line:

```
mapTypeId: google.mapsp.mapTypeId.ROADMAP
//--------------------^-^
```

it should be

```
mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
```

Comment: Yeah man, the maps is showing Up now, but json archive with markers not yet

Answer (score 0):

Try assign width also

```
 <style>
  html, body {
    height: 100%;
    width:100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }
  #map {
    height: 100%;
    width: 500px;
  }
</style>
```